# Excel conditional formatting with blanks and Today()

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get a cell to highlight, given 2 criteria. The cell must be blank, and today's date must be after a predetermined date that is listed in another cell(R8C3). I'm also using R1C1 notation, but understand A1 notation as well.
The part I don't understand is that each criteria works independently, but when I use the `AND` function it no longer works. The relative references are used since this formatting will span multiple columns.

`=ISBLANK(RC)` evaluates to true and highlights correctly.

`=TODAY()>=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(R8C3),COLUMN(RC)))` evaluates to true and highlights appropriately.

`=AND(ISBLANK(RC),TODAY()>=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(R8C3),COLUMN(RC))))` Does not highlight.

A slightly modified version pasted in a cell ( to check that the formula works) evaluates appropriately to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
`=AND(ISBLANK(RC3),TODAY()>=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(R8C3),COLUMN(RC3))))`

I'm using Excel 2010 (version 14) on a Windows 7 device.

Comment: I just ran a test where I put **1** in `A1` and **2** in `A2`. Then tried the following conditional format (which worked): `=AND(A1=1,A2=2)`. Your best bet is to pull the formula from the conditional formatting to a cell and evaluate it. Then see if the result is, in fact, `true`.

Comment: Further investigation... RC notation in a new notebook with `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1),4,0))` returns `#REF!` while `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1),4,1))` works as expected. The conditional formatting may want you to use the 0 in the 4th argument if your default notation is RC.

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps I was not clear enough, I did try pulling the formula from the conditional formatting and pasting it in a cell, however, given that it is checking to see if the cell is blank, I cannot use the exact same formula without creating circular reference. That is what I mean by "slightly modified version" above. As for using the two optional `ADDRESS` parameters, those did not change the effect; it still works in a cell (modified to not reference itself), but not as a conditional format.

Comment: The optional [a1] parameter on the `ADDRESS` function should only need to be set to match the [a1] parameter in the `INDIRECT` function, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=(J$1>K$1)*(ISBLANK(A1))
```

where `J1` has the current date and `K1` the threshold date.

Comment: This concept works! I somehow forgot that `TRUE` and `FALSE` can be used as 1 and 0 in operations! I modified it to suit my purpose:
`=(TODAY()>=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(R8C3),COLUMN(RC))))*(ISBLANK(RC))`
The `INDIRECT` `ADDRESS` `ROW` `COLUMN` combination was necessary so the conditional formatting always looks at row 8 in the column that is being formatted. The range this is applied to spans multiple columns.

Comment: `=(TODAY()>=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(R8C3),COLUMN(RC))))*(ISBLANK(RC))*(NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(R8C3),COLUMN(RC))))))`

Comment: Above is the final version of my conditional formatting - the last `(NOT(ISBLANK...` bit stops it from highlighting if I don't have  due date listed in `R8C3`.

Answer (score 0):

The indirect statement seems unnecessarily convoluted... why not just use a mixed reference?

```
=AND(ISBLANK(RC), TODAY()>=R8C)
```

Comment: The `INDIRECT` statement is because the `ADDRESS` statement returns text. I can't use a fixed reference because I only refer to a fixed row, the column varies, with different dates in the columns of that row. If that makes sense...

Comment: Okay it's clearer now what you want. However this should still be possible using a mixed reference. You seem to start with an address, turn it into text, then turn it back into an address for no reason. Can you please try my updated formula? This keeps the row fixed and still allows the column to vary using a mixed reference.

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a go when I'm back at my computer